# How to paste a worksheet copied from another workbook into an existing worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have found a little difficult to achieve copying an existing worksheet from a workbook, let's called it, "WB_RAW" and pasting it into an existing worksheet in another workbook. So far I have the next code, which I get from another post's answer. This code copies succesfully the worksheet but it creates a new worksheet in the workbook, let's called it, "Final_WB" instead of pasting the info into an existing workbook.

```
    Sub ImportSheet()
    Dim sImportFile As String, sFile As String
    Dim sThisBk As Workbook
    Dim vfilename As Variant
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set sThisBk = ActiveWorkbook
    sImportFile = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks, *.xls; *.xlsx", Title:="Open Workbook")
    If sImportFile = "False" Then
        MsgBox "No File Selected!"
        Exit Sub

    Else
        vfilename = Split(sImportFile, "\")
        sFile = vfilename(UBound(vfilename))
        Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:=sImportFile

        Set wbBk = Workbooks(sFile)
        With wbBk
            If SheetExists("MTM Datos") Then
                Set wsSht = .Sheets("MTM Datos")
                wsSht.Copy before:=sThisBk.Sheets("B012")
                ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value
            Else
                MsgBox "There is no sheet with name :MTM Datos in:" & vbCr & .Name
            End If
            wbBk.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
Private Function SheetExists(sWSName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Worksheets(sWSName)
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then SheetExists = True
End Function
```

Please help me, it's been a while since I used VBA for the last time so I do not remembe well how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line you copy a full sheet with data 
`wsSht.Copy before:=sThisBk.Sheets("Bimbo12")`

Change it to

```
wsSht.Cells.Copy sThisBk.Sheets("Bimbo12").Cells(1,1)
Application.CutCopyMode=False
```

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot. I've just tried that. It Works perfectly. Thanks for answering so quickly

Comment: Hi, I have another question. Is it posible to copy just the visible cells? Because I have some columns hidden that I don't want to copy. How could I do that??

Comment: I am new here, I am still trying to figure out how to marked as answered jeje

Comment: How dare you ask another question before accepting answer, upvote???? Just kidding.....  for only visible cells use: `wsSht.UsedRange.SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible).Copy`

Comment: Sorry for that jeje is the answer accepted? and does that mean that my question is answered?

Comment: NP... I was just kidding. But its accepted now.http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.... cheers!! If you have more questions always start a new question.